# Creating and calling a stack of functions with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to have a list of functions that can be executed at a later point. I am unsure about a good way to pass arguments into these functions. The idea is to have various objects register functions and have another object decide whether and in which order these functions are executed.

I came up with this

```py
class Place():

    def __init__(self):
        self.things = []

    def register_add_thing(self, thing):

        def add_thing(place, thing):
            place.things.append(thing)

        return (add_thing, [self, thing])

    def register_add_ting(self, ting):

        def add_thing():
            nonlocal self
            nonlocal ting
            self.things.append(ting)

        return add_thing


p = Place()
functions = []
functions.append(p.register_add_ting('toast'))
for f in functions:
    f()

print(p.things)

functions = []
functions.append(p.register_add_thing('bread'))
for f in functions:
    f[0](*f[1])

print(p.things)
```

Is there a nicer way to handle the arguments?

Comment: How do you want to handle the arguments?

Comment: I don't think you need `nonlocal` there

Comment: Maybe you want [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Answer (score 0):

If your arguments are fixed at the time of registration, then you have couple of options. I assume you don't like the design of returning the registration function and its arguments.. later called as `f[0](*f[1])`

```
def register_add_thing_func(self, thing):
    def wrapper(place, thing):
        def inner():
            place.things.append(thing)
        return inner
    return wrapper(self, thing)

def register_add_thing_lambda(self, thing):
    return lambda : self.things.append(thing)

...

functions.append(p.register_add_thing_func('bread'))
functions.append(p.register_add_thing_lambda('bread'))

for f in functions:
    f()

print(p.things)
```